# Can I debug two local projects running on IIS (not Cassini)

Tags: debugging, iis, wcf

I have a WCF service and a web application that both need to be hosted in local IIS virtual directories. I start up the WCF project and then when I try to debug the web app at the same time a popup tells me "Unable to start debugging on the web server. Unable to do an AutoAttach." The same problem happens if I try to manually attach to aspnet_wp.exe after the WCF service has already started.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried firing them both off somehow (basically to get processes) then attaching the debugger to each manually?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Wyatt,

I created a solution with both projects. Then I set the Startup projects to have both projects start without debugging. Then after they start, I manually attach to the process and get debugging on both sides.

Comment: you can fire up new processes from the solution explorer once you're running the debugger, if memory serves it's "start new debug instance" or something along those lines.